# Yii2 $_GET parameter in URL

Tags: php, url, get, yii2

I'm relatively new to yii2, and I wonder how can I make my url look good. The question is:
I have my url: `/path/projects/?url=my-link`
and I need it to be like this: `/path/projects/my-link/`
It would be amazing if someone can send me direct solution, not links to documentation

Comment: Nobody is going to send you a direct solution my friend. Have a read of this https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#using-pretty-urls. Let people know what you have previously tried

Comment: What part of the documentation couldn't you follow? If we tried to give you a direct solution, it would be pretty much a copy of the content on the link that @Kyle sent. If you update your question to show what you have tried so far, and what exactly didn't work, it would help give you a solution you could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your config, where you declare your components, add or modify the urlManager like this:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'projects/<url>' => 'projects/ACTION',
            ],
        ],
```

In order for this to work, first, the path `projects/action` has to match your controller action, and then `projects/<url>` means that when you build a link you need to pass the parameters required with the url, example: 
`<a href="projects/ACTION?url=test" >test</a>`

Yii then will transform the url to the pretty url you want.

I recommend you to use the slug field, and use the default behavior [sluggable](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-sluggablebehavior)